# How do I fill Excel sheet cells with only the filled text boxes without any empty cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and recently I have been developing a calculator to help do my work. I have created a form with multiple check boxes and text boxes, in my Excel sheet, I have a table that should be filled by the user form. However, I've run into issues, in the user form there is a check box that when checked the user must enter into the text box, I have got exactly eight similar categories (check boxes and text boxes), so all checked boxes and all filled text boxes should be displayed into the cells in the sheet, however they way I done it, is that I use the line:

`Range("E5").Value = "Project Manager"`

For each of the eight categories, it must fill the cells without leaving any empty cells.

For example, user checks 5 of the 8 boxes and accordingly fills out the text box for each one, if they skipped one of the boxes, it must not do the same when printing them out on the cells.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim PMdays As Integer

If PMcheckBx.Value Then
    Range("E5").Value = "Project Manager"

    PMdays = PMtextBx.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = PMdays
End If

End Sub
```

As such, I have attached an image of how I want it to look like and how mine looks like now to help you understand my problem further.

[How my sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYQEF.jpg)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZSFq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim PMdays As Integer, c As Range

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value '<< start list here

    If PMcheckBx.Value Then
        c.Resize(1,2).Value = Array("Project Manager", PMtextBx.Value)
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'move down one row
    End If

    'next 7 checkboxes 

End Sub
```

Note no ActiveCell/Select/Activate needed.